# Dereferencing 'void *' pointer when using struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers, dereference

I'm trying to make use of [inode](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/inode.c)'s i_private and store a struct with name and block number in it:

```
struct osffs_inode_private_info* info;
inode->i_private = kzalloc(sizeof(struct osffs_inode_private_info), GFP_KERNEL);
inode->i_private = info;
strncpy(inode->i_private->name, "private succ", OSFFS_MAX_NAME_LEN);
```

Where the struct is defined as follows:

```
struct osffs_inode_private_info {
    char name[OSFFS_MAX_NAME_LEN];
    __be64 block;
};
```

When I try to compile, I get a warning that I am

> "dereferencing a 'void *' pointer"

and an error

> "request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union"

in the line where I do the `strncpy()`.

I know there are many threads/questions about dereferencing a void pointer and it seems like I just have to do a cast or such. But unfortunately, I don't know how to apply that to my problem.

Comment: What is the definition of `inode`?

Comment: `inode->i_private = info;` why do you assign after kmallo()? You may want a "deep" copy here (memcpy)

Comment: @MikeCAT, [`struct inode *`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in your code

```
inode->i_private = kzalloc(sizeof(struct osffs_inode_private_info), GFP_KERNEL);
inode->i_private = info;
```

you're leaking memory. In the later statement, you're overwriting the previous pointer in `inode->i_private` by assigning *to* it.

maybe you wanted to do

```
info = inode->i_private;
```

That said, the issue in the question is with the said usage of `i_private`. This being a `void` pointer, cannot be dereferenced.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.3, *Structure and union members*

> The first operand of the `->` operator shall have type ‘‘pointer to atomic, qualified, or
>   unqualified structure’’ or ‘‘pointer to atomic, qualified, or unqualified union’’,[...]

That's why, you have to cast the `void *` to the pointer-to-required-type to make that eligible to be used as the left-operand for member access operator (`->`).

You need to use something like

```
 strncpy( ((struct osffs_inode_private_info *)(inode->i_private))->name, 
           "private succ", 
            OSFFS_MAX_NAME_LEN);
```

Comment: It would be more readable to use a local pointer variable though: `struct osffs_inode_private_info *pinfo = inode->i_private;` and `strncpy(pinfo->name, "private succ", OSFFS_MAX_NAME_LEN);`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Right, you certainly can. I think once we change to `info = inode->i_private;` in the code, rest part is pretty straight. :)